# Update element attribute after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to update `onClick` attribute of an element after a successful ajax function.But its not works as expected .I explored net on this but those have not taken me to a solution.

### Below is my codes:-

```
$("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").attr("onClick", "checkMinOrder(' + data.min_order + ',' + data.sub_total + ')");
```

Here `proceed_cart` is name attr.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the parameters in the function correctly. Try this:

```
$("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").attr("onClick", "checkMinOrder('" + data.min_order + "','" + data.sub_total +
  "')");
```

**UPDATE**

You can check the snippet below to see it in action:

```js
var data = {
  min_order: 'test1',
  sub_total: 'test2'
};
var onclickAttr = $("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").attr("onClick");
console.log('Original onclick value: ' + onclickAttr);

onclickAttr = $("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").attr("onClick", "checkMinOrder('" + data.min_order + "','" + data.sub_total + "')");
console.log("New onclick value: " + $("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").attr("onClick"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name='proceed_cart' onClick='checkMinOrder()'>
  Button
</button>
```

Comment: What does not work? You don't see the attribute added? Or there is a problem with your AJAX? Please provide more information/code, otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is bad practice.

Pure Javascript:

```
document.querySelector("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").addEventListener("click", function()
{
  checkMinOrder(data.min_order, data.sub_total);
});
```

Or jQuery:

```
$("button[name = 'proceed_cart']").click(function()
{
  checkMinOrder(data.min_order, data.sub_total);
});
```

Comment: Check developers console for errors. Check if your element selector is right.

Answer (score 0):

Make it little simpler may be,

If you require quotes to be passed?

```
var handlerMethod = "checkMinOrder('"+ data.min_order +"','"+ data.sub_total +"')";
```

otherwise,

```
var handlerMethod = "checkMinOrder("+ data.min_order +","+ data.sub_total +")";
```

And do it,

```
$("button[name = proceed_cart]").attr("onClick", handlerMethod);
```